# Get current menu item label for specific parent menu

Tags: menus, labels

I have one custom menu in theme.
You can see Buying menu have child archive page.
i.e Active Listing. So what I want to do is at the top of the archive page for buying I want to display menu label.

Suppose I am on a page I want to show "Active Listing" at the top of archive list.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following empty div where you want to display current menu label

```
<div class="menu-label-container"></div>
```

and add the following script in footer of the page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if(jQuery('#nav li.current-menu-item  a').html())
        jQuery('.menu-label-container').html(jQuery('#nav li.current-menu-item  a').html());       
});
```

Tell me whether this solution is working for you or i will find another solution.

Comment: I want to do it with wordpress functions or php code, not with jQuery, BTW thanks